# Control data in a group by MySQL SELECT

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a table like this:

```
+------------------------+
| Id IdGroup Name Status |
+------------------------+
| 0  P.1     Foo  Ok     |
| 1  P.1     Foo No     |
| 2  P.2     Foo3 No     |
+------------------------+
```

I want to make a select with group by like this:

```
SELECT IdGroup, Name, Status FROM footable GROUP BY IdGroup
```

and if all "Status" values of grouped rows are ok.
The result that I want is:

```
+--------------------+
| P.1     Foo  Maybe |
+--------------------+
| P.2     Foo3 No    |
+--------------------+
```

It's possible?

Comment: Not possible and the query itself is wrong.

Comment: Hi @RavindraGullapalli, why it's wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Compare the count of `Ok` rows with the total count of rows in each group.

```
SELECT IdGroup, Name, IF(COUNT(*) = SUM(Status = 'Ok'), 'Maybe', 'No') As Status
FROM footable
GROUP BY IdGroup
```

Note that this will select a random `Name` from each group. The question didn't indicate how the name should be selected.

Comment: Not "random", "indeterminate" ;)

Comment: A distinction that makes no practical difference.

Comment: No, I'm sorry! It was a typing error in the question, the records in the same group have the same name!

Comment: @Barmar . . . It is a very important distinction.  "Random" has a specific meaning in statistics and probability and it is very different from "indeterminate".

Comment: @GordonLinoff This isn't statistics. I'm using it to mean "unpredictable", which is another definition of the word.